# Rest API Composite - Error 302

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, httprequest, composite

I am using Composite API to get the opportunity record but facing 302 error

```
{
 "compositeRequest" : [
    {
        "method" : "GET",
        "url" : "/services/data/v42.0/query/?q=select+id,Opportunity_No__c+from+Opporunity+where+Opportunity_No__c='OP-0000014'",
        "referenceId" : "refOpporrunityInfo"                               
    }]
}
```

**URL:** https://vei-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/services/data/v42.0/composite

**Method:** POST

**Header:**

- **Authorization:** Bearer token
- **Content-Type:** application/json

Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Lavanya

Comment: 302 is not an error, it's an informative message redirecting the client to a different URL. This happens when you use the wrong URL. This is true for *any* API call in Salesforce when you use the wrong URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the instance url of your org 
https://vei-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v42.0/composite

URL: https://vei-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v42.0/composite
Method: POST
Header:
Authorization: Bearer {token}
Content-Type: application/json

```
{
 "compositeRequest" : [
    {
        "method" : "GET",
        "url" : "/services/data/v42.0/query/?q=select+id,Opportunity_No__c+from+Opportunity+where+Opportunity_No__c='OP-0000014'",
        "referenceId" : "refOpporrunityInfo"                               
    }]
}
```

Now it's working please refer below link

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?feedtype=RECENT&criteria=BESTANSWERS#!/feedtype=MINE

Thanks,

Lavanya

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the table name after "FROM" (*Opporunity*)

Try with the following request:

```
{
 "compositeRequest" : [
    {
        "method" : "GET",
        "url" : "/services/data/v42.0/query/?q=select+id,Opportunity_No__c+from+Opportunity+where+Opportunity_No__c='OP-0000014'",
        "referenceId" : "refOpporrunityInfo"                               
    }]
}
```